# Auto hiding UINavigationBar and UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have an iPhone app that is based on a navigation controller.

I have a main view controller that displays a list of articles, and a detail view, where you can see one article in a `UIWebView`. For the detail view, I have the navigation bar on the top, and a `UIToolbar` on the bottom.

I'd like to auto-hide them with a slide animation (to top and bottom) and restore them when tapping the screen. I thought this would be a standard function, but couldn't find how to do it.

As a reference, this is what Stanza or the NYT app do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set up a method that runs this on a tap event:

```
if (![navigationController isNavigationBarHidden])
  [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]; // hides
else
  [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES]; // shows
```

As for the `UIToolbar`, it is a `UIView` subclass, so you should be able to pretty easily set up a [custom animation](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/sliding-views-on-and-off-screen-creating-a-reusable-sliding-message-widget.html) for sliding this in and out of sight.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
BOOL hide = ![self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:hide animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also quite a useful method for UIVIewController.

```
- (BOOL) hidesBottomBarWhenPushed {
//hide a toolbar or whatever
return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess recently you can use `self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnTap = true;`